# Showing that for any positive sequence $(a_n), \limsup \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge 4$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x:=\limsup \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ . Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given.

If $x$ is infinite then there is nothing to prove so let's consider the case when $x$ is finite.

There exists a $K$ such that
for large $n\ge K$ we have $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt x+\epsilon\implies \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n+1}}\gt \frac 1{ x+\epsilon}\overbrace{\implies}^{*} \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}\gt \frac 1{x+\epsilon}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt x+\epsilon \implies \limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x.$

Infact at $(*)$, it can also be concluded that $\frac{a_n}{a_r}\gt \frac 1{x+\epsilon}$ for any $r\le n$. That is, $\limsup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_r}=x$ for every $r\le n$.

I don't understand how to proceed further. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** I am using the following definition of $\limsup (x_n)=:y$

1. If sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded from above then $y$ is defined to be a number which has the property: For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\ge N\implies x_n\lt y+\epsilon$ and that for infinitely many $n$, the inequality $y-\epsilon\lt x_n$ holds.
2. If sequence $(x_n)$ is unbounded from above, then $y:=+\infty$.

Or the following definition can also be used:

$\limsup x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m\ge n} x_m$

Comment: Identical question found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Climsup%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_1%2Ba_2%2B...%2Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_n%7D%5Cge%204%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks a lot. I'm going through the answer available there. :)

Comment: @MartinR: I request opening of this question as the answer available there somehow uses polynomials. I mean I don't understand the approach there. Also, comments below the answer seem to indicate some issue with the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The alternative “easier proof“ seems to be correct. You have $t_n \ge f(t_{n-1})$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{L(1-x)} > x$, $L < 4$. This implies that $(t_n)$ is increasing and diverges to infinity. On the other hand $t_n \le 1$.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks. I had not seen that. I'm trying to understand this last statement. I'll comment when I have a better understanding of why $f(x)\gt x$.

Comment: There is also a solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1247405p6406897

Comment: @MartinR: In the answer linked earlier, Question 1: $\frac 1{1-x}\gt 1\implies f(x)\gt \frac 1L\gt \frac 14$. I don't understand why $f(x)\gt x$ (I understand that $x\in (0,1)$).  Question 2: Assuming $f(x)\gt x$ to be true, $t_n$ is increasing but what implies that $t_n$ is divergent as we know that $t_n$ is actually bounded? Confusion 3: I think $L=0$ should also be considered separately and that's why I was afraid to use contradiction for trying to prove the result :'(.  I'm looking at the answer in second link now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130929/discussion-between-martin-r-and-koro).